# Django error creating user manager for AbstractUser

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-views

I have written a custom search for my user model using custom Manager however, I am getting the following error:

```
user = UserModel._default_manager.get_by_natural_key(username)
AttributeError: 'ProfileManager' object has no attribute 'get_by_natural_key'
```

Below are my AbstractUser and Manager how can I resolve this issue?

```
class ProfileManager(models.Manager):
    
    def search(self, search_text):
        search_vectors = ( 
              SearchVector(
                  'username', weight='A', config='english'
            
                ) + SearchVector(
                  'first_name', 'last_name' , weight='B', config='english'
                ) + SearchVector(
                  'bio', weight='C', config='english'
            
                )
              )
        search_query = SearchQuery(
            search_text, config=' english__unaccent'
        )
        search_rank = SearchRank(search_vectors,search_query)
        trigram = TrigramSimilarity(
            'username',search_text
        ) + TrigramSimilarity(
            'last_name',search_text
        ) 
        qs = (
            self.get_queryset()
            .filter(sv=search_query)
            .annotate(rank=search_rank, trigram=trigram, bs=Greatest('rank','trigram'))
            .filter(Q(bs__gte=0.35))
            .order_by('-bs')
        )
        
        return qs

class Profile(AbstractUser):
    
    '''
    Some of my user fields 
    '''

    objects = ProfileManager()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The class **`ProfileManager`** should be inherited from [**`BaseUserManager`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.BaseUserManager)  since you are dealing with *auth user manager*

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager


class ProfileManager(BaseUserManager):
    ...
```